# Is change detection in Angular triggered by @Input changes also?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

[This](https://mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/) site says:

> In the default change detection strategy, Angular will run the change
> detector any time @Input() data is changed or modified

But in reality, change detection is triggered only on the following three conditions (as the same site says a little before):

> - any browser event (click, keyup, etc.)
> - getInterval() and setTimeout()
> - HTTP requests via XMLHttpRequest

So (unlike the statement at the start), change detection is NOT run when `@Input` changes (but only in the given three conditions). Its ***during the execution*** of change detection that @Input changes must be getting detected. Am I right?

Also, why would `@Input` trigger change detection when inputs can only change upon the above three conditions, and for those three conditions, we're already triggering change detection. A separate triggering of change detection on `@Input` change seems redundant

Comment: Something somewhere in your app caused the data in your @Input to be changed. That event will trigger change detection for the whole app if you're in default change detection.

Comment: @WillAlexander But change detection for the whole app will be triggered if an event fires somewhere without changing any `@input`. So why is it said that "Angular will run the change detector any time `@Input()` data is changed or modified"

Comment: @WillAlexander Also, why would `@Input` trigger change detection when inputs can only change upon the above three conditions, and in those three conditions, we're already triggering change detection. A separate triggering of change detection on `@Input` change seems redundant

Comment: I can understand your confusion. What I'm saying is that whichever event triggered the change in the `@Input` data _will also_ trigger change detection, so _indirectly_, a change in `@Input` data always corresponds to a change detection cycle. There isn't a "separate triggering". It's just that whatever made the data change is an __event__, meaning a cycle is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

change detector and change detection is not the same thing. You are right that change detection will be run on those three condition but this only means that it will check all the components if there is need to rerender them.

So if Input() data has changed from the previous time change detection was executed this component is marked as dirty and it will be rerendered. However if there was not any changes in component from the previous change detection cycle(so the input has the same value) component won't be rerendered(change DETECTOR won't be runned)